# useState and localStorage: argument of type 'string null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, local-storage

I'm using NextJS, and i am trying to make a state persist using localStorage, i did it like this:

```
const [reportFavorite, setReportFavorite] = useState([
    'captura',
    'software',
    'upload',
  ] as any)

  useEffect(() => {
    setReportFavorite(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('reportFavorite')))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('reportFavorite', reportFavorite)
  }, [reportFavorite])
```

But TypeScript returns this error: `argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

I read some answers on StackOverflow telling me that if i did:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setReportFavorite(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('reportFavorite')!))
  }, [])
```

Using the `!`, it would fix it, but it didn't, if i do that i get another error saying `invalid character on line`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [reportFavorite, setReportFavorite] = useState([
    'captura',
    'software',
    'upload',
  ] as any)

  useEffect(() => {
    const reportFavouriteInStorage = localStorage.getItem('reportFavorite');
    if(!!reportFavouriteInStorage){
      setReportFavorite(JSON.parse(reportFavouriteInStorage))
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('reportFavorite', reportFavorite)
  }, [reportFavorite])
```

Comment: Im having the same error that i had when i tried using '!', says invalid character: https://i.imgur.com/4vLZS23.png

Comment: What if you just remove the JSON.parse alltogether?

Comment: Can you update your question with your complete component?

Comment: It works without the JSON.parse, you were right. I just had trouble making it work with a boolean useState. It was always set to false on localStorage. But i managed my way around it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that

```
useEffect(() => {
 const reportFavorite =  (localStorage.getItem('reportFavorite') != null ) ? localStorage.getItem('reportFavorite') : "";
setReportFavorite(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(reportFavorite)))
  }, [])
```